# Unable to connect to local Openfire server (using smack api)

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

i am trying this code on android to connect to my local XMPP Server

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Create a connection
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    "192.168.43.170", 5223, "192.168.43.170");
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            }
            try {
                // SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
                connection.login("nagham","123456");
                // Set the status to available
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                connection.sendPacket(presence);
                setConnection(connection);
                Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                    Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                            .getUser());

                    Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                }
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {    
        }
        }
    });
```

But i get the following exception:

```
    05-16 02:10:16.580: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(24289): Failed to connect to 192.168.43.170
05-16 02:10:16.588: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(24289): XMPPError connecting to 192.168.43.170:5223.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to 192.168.43.170:5223.
05-16 02:10:16.588: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(24289):   -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.170 (port 5223): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-16 02:10:16.588: E/AndroidRuntime(24289): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5736
05-16 02:10:16.588: E/AndroidRuntime(24289): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
```

Where am I going wrong ?
note that i am using asmack-2010.05.07

Comment: Do not use legacy SSL(5223) connection, try 5222 port

Comment: yeah, thanks i've changed the port number and i've noticed that the firewall on my labtop is running, so when i disable it every thing goes on

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem, just in change the port number from 5223 to 5222 
and every one don't forget that your firewall must be disabled.